# odbc connection from windows machine to mysql server running on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, connectivity, odbc

I was able to install mysql server on an ubuntu machine and set up a test data base, created a user and granted that user access to the database. 
I also changed the binding address to the IP of the server and opened up `port 3306`.

I am also able to access the mysql database from another remote linux machine using the mysql client.

My question is, is it possible to access the mysql server from a windows machine using the odbc data source administrator with SQL server native client 10.0? is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible as SQL Server Native Client is a client library for SQL Server, not for MySQL. If you want to access a MySQL server through ODBC, then you need the [MySQL ODBC driver (Connector/ODBC)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).